# How to find function $f$ bounded from top by $x^\alpha$ and from bottom by $log^k(x)$

Tags: analysis

$k > 1, \alpha > 0, x > 0$

If $\alpha \ge 1$ then answer is $f(x)=x$ and it's easy to show by calculating two limits and using l'Hospital rule. 
$f$ should be bounded by those two functions beggining from some $x_0$

Problem is when $\alpha < 1$, because for example $x$ grows faster than $\sqrt x$.

Next problem is that $f$ cannot be dependant on $\alpha$ nor $k$.

I tried manipulating with series and come up with "middle" series, but no sucess. Guessing method is not easier for me. I'd really appreciate some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "f cannot be dependent neither on α nor on k." Are you sure about this requirement? Seems like not quite feasible to me if you want to stick with this requirement.

Comment: Hey @peter.petrov yes i'm sure

Comment: What about $x\mapsto e^{\sqrt{\ln x}}$?

Comment: @ClementC. What if $ln(x) < 0$

Comment: @ClementC. it's looking very nice!

Comment: @peter.petrov The domain is not specified... my answer is basically asymptotic. But on the other hand, there can only be an asymptotic answer, since for instance $\ln^6 x > x$ for small values of  $x$.

Comment: Thanks peter for your comment, x should be greater than 0.

Comment: @Chris It means the domain is: x greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: I edited question with little detail, sorry about it, i assumed it was obvious, cause simplest example $ln^2 x > x^2$ as x goes to 0 shows it couldn't be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I assume the question is asymptotic (i.e., "for any $x$ sufficiently large, where *sufficiently large* refers to $x\geq x^\ast=x^\ast(\alpha,k)$". Indeed, otherwise it is easy to see that there is no hope to get $x^\alpha \geq f(x) \geq \ln^k x$ for all $x>0$ (and any $\alpha,k$), since for instance $k=2,\alpha=1$ yields
$$
\log^2 x > x
$$
in a neighborhood of $0$.

For an asymptotic guarantee, take $$f\colon x\geq 1 \mapsto e^{\sqrt{\ln x}}.$$
(you can define $f$ on $(0,1)$ any way you want, since it does not matter). Then, observe that $x^\alpha = e^{\alpha\ln x}$, and $\ln^k x = e^{k\ln\ln x}$, you get that for all $\alpha,k >0$, $\ln^k x \leq f(x) \leq x^\alpha$ for $x$ large enough (by comparing the growth rate of the exponents).

Comment: More generally, when dealing with comparisons like this (for a parameter going to infinity), expressing all terms as $e^{[...]}$ (or $2^{[...]}$ for a more computer-science-ey-flavor) and comparing the exponents is often a good approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot Clement, this is very clever and nice solution, thanks a lot